# An intrinsic characterization of projective varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

After I learnt about projective schemes over a field, I tried to figure out if for a given projective scheme there is some "natural" closed immersion into a projective space. It turns out unless you impose some restrictions on Picard rank, nothing like this exists. Yet somehow, most of the geometric properties of a projective variety do not really depend on the choice of a closed immersion. One can also characterize complete varieties pretty intrinsically.

Therefore, the question: does there exist a characterization of projective morphisms of schemes which does not involve the word "exists"?

Comment: This would imply to choose a canonical ample sheaf inside the Picard group. and it doesn't seem feasible, in my opinion.

Comment: @LeoAlonso I am not entirely sure this would imply that we have a canonical choice of ample sheaf. There may be some non-trivial condition equivalent to existence of a very ample line bundle but which does not itself give the choice of such a bundle (though I agree that such scenario is somewhat unlikely).

Answer (score 3):

The following may be relevant. Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. A variety is an integral separated scheme of finite type over $k$. Benoist [has shown](https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.0975) that a normal variety is quasi-projective iff every finite subset is contained in an affine open subvariety. If you have reasonable definitions, properness+quasi-projectiveness [is equivalent](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BCL) to projectiveness.